# Show Custom Add To Cart Template on Certain Products for Guest in Magento

Tags: magento, php

I want to force users to be register on order page to add certain products in the cart. I've a custom `Add to Cart` phtml. To activate this special `add to cart` for certain products I use the following code in products as follows

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
  <action method="setTemplate">   
    <template>catalog/product/view/customtemplate.phtml</template>
  </action>
</reference>
```

Can anybody give me directions in how to force users to be logged for order those certain products to use this template i.e. only logged in users can use my custom template?

Comment: just check session before that. If session exists then display or whatever you want Else not.

Answer (score 0):

in the template file `catalog/product/view/customtemplate.phtml`, you can check if the customer is logged-in

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    // display the contents of the template file
}
```